# How to translate drawn object

Tags: java, graphics

I'm now doing connect 4 game and i'm drawing the token and I need to translate it by an event like clicking right or left button ... This is my code

```
public static Graphics myInstance;

public Executer(){
    setTitle("Connect 4");
    setSize(500,700);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myInstance = this.getGraphics();
}

public void paint (Graphics g){
    //Drawing the grid
    Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    g.setColor(black);
    //g.drawString("Hi", 50, 50);
    g.drawRect(20, 200, 441, 400);
    for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
        g.drawLine(83 + i*63, 200, 83 + i*63, 600);

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        g.drawLine(20 ,267 + i*67, 461 , 267 + i*67);

    //End Drawing the grid

}

public static void main (String[] args){
    Executer e = new Executer();

    //Drawing Red Tokken
    Color red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
    myInstance.setColor(red);
    myInstance.fillOval(29, 150, 50, 50);
}
```

I Don't know which function is used to translate I've searched and I found nothing or I should clear the drawing and repaint from beginning ?!

Comment: What do you mean "translate", you want to change it's position?

Comment: First and foremost, get rid of that static myInstance variable as it is breaking several rules: it is static, it is a Graphics variable obtained by calling `getGraphics()` making it short-lived and unstable. This is not how to do Swing graphics. Instead you will want to draw in the paintComponent overridden method of JPanel as most any tutorial or search of this site will show you.

Comment: Exactly, translation means re positioning

Comment: Either animate the position with a Swing Timer or drag it via a MouseListener.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471010/placing-correct-discs-connect-four-java-game-with-drawing-panel/30472078#30472078) which basically calculates the "column" position of the token based on the mouse's current location over the component

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels well I'll need that instance lately as i'll change tokens color every turn ... dynamic changing far away from the paint function !

Comment: No you won't, trust me, @MadProgrammer and I have been doing Swing graphics and animation for years, and the best way to do this is not what you're trying to do. Instead to change color, either swap ImageIcons or change the state of a non-static instance field, one that is used in the paintComponent method. Again, please read any basic tutorial on Swing graphics and you'll see. Please start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: Do NOT, EVER use `getGraphics`!  This is NOT how custom painting is done in Swing.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting should be done in Swing

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. First and fore-most, don't get your Graphics object as you're doing, by calling `getGraphics()` on a component. For one, your code is almost guaranteed to give you a null reference and thereby risk causing a NullPointerException. But for another, even if you were successful, the Graphics object thus obtained would be short lived and would risk becoming non-functioning or null as your program ran.
2. Instead, you will want to draw within the paintComponent method of a class that extends JPanel or JComponent.
3. Here you will use the Graphics object given to you by the JVM, one that should remain stable **for the duration of the paintComponent method**.
4. Don't forget to call the super's method within your override to do housekeeping drawing.
5. You will want to change the state of an instance field, perhaps one called `diskColor`, that will then be used within paintComponent. This will allow outside classes the ability to change the color drawn within paintComponent.
6. Another option is to use ImageIcons held by JLabels to hold your drawings, and actually this is what I'd choose, since you could create a grid of JLabels, giving them MouseListeners, and thereby allow your game to be played.

---

For example with ImageIcons:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ConnectGrid extends JPanel {
    public static final int ROWS = 7;
    public static final int COLS = 6;
    public static final int DIAMETER = 80;

    // color of blank icon, placeholder for grid position without disk
    private static final Color BLANK_COLOR = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // all colors -- placeholder, red and yellow
    public static final Color[] COLORS = { BLANK_COLOR, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW };

    // ImageIcons mapped to color
    private static final Map<Color, Icon> iconMap = new HashMap<>();
    private static final int GAP = 2;

    // JLabel grid that holds the colored icons
    private JLabel[][] labelGrid = new JLabel[ROWS][COLS];
    private Color turn = Color.RED; // whose turn is it?

    static {
        // create our colored image icons
        int w = DIAMETER;
        int h = DIAMETER;
        int imgType = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
        for (Color color : COLORS) {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, imgType);
            Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
            // smooth drawing
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            // draw the color
            g2.setColor(color);
            g2.fillOval(GAP, GAP, w - 2 * GAP, h - 2 * GAP);
            // draw a black border
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));
            g2.setColor(Color.black);
            g2.drawOval(GAP, GAP, w - 2 * GAP, h - 2 * GAP);
            g2.dispose();
            // create ImageIcon and put in iconMap, mapped to color
            iconMap.put(color, new ImageIcon(img));
        }
    }

    public ConnectGrid() {
        // JPanel to hold grid of JLabels
        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS, GAP, GAP));
        // create grid of JLabels, add to gridPanel JPanel
        // fill labels with blank icon, add MouseListener
        for (int row = 0; row < labelGrid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < labelGrid[row].length; col++) {
                // must swap the row numbers since 0th row is on the bottom
                labelGrid[ROWS - row - 1][col] = new JLabel(
                        iconMap.get(BLANK_COLOR));
                gridPanel.add(labelGrid[ROWS - row - 1][col]);
                labelGrid[ROWS - row - 1][col].addMouseListener(new MyMouse(
                        ROWS - row - 1, col));
            }
        }

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new ResetAction("Reset")));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private int row;
        private int col;

        public MyMouse(int row, int col) {
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
            Icon icon = label.getIcon();
            if (icon != iconMap.get(BLANK_COLOR)) {
                // if label already has a colored icon, ignore mouse press
                return;
            }
            // if not at bottom row
            if (row != 0
            // and label below has a blank icon
                    && labelGrid[row - 1][col].getIcon() == iconMap
                            .get(BLANK_COLOR)) {
                // ignore mouse press
                return;
            }
            // get color for this turn
            icon = iconMap.get(turn);
            // set label's icon
            label.setIcon(icon);
            // toggle the value of turn
            // TODO: check for win here
            turn = (turn == COLORS[1]) ? COLORS[2] : COLORS[1];
        }
    }

    private class ResetAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ResetAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (JLabel[] labelRow : labelGrid) {
                for (JLabel label : labelRow) {
                    label.setIcon(iconMap.get(BLANK_COLOR));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ConnectGrid mainPanel = new ConnectGrid();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ConnectGrid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing errors within calling getGraphics() it's working properly till now ... is there some link taking about this issue with simpler explanation ?!

Comment: @Naggar: how specifically is it working / not working? Are you seeing colors?